# Rails ActiveRecord: validate single attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

Is there any way I can validate a single attribute in ActiveRecord?

Something like:

```
ac_object.valid?(attribute_name)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can implement your own method in your model. Something like this

```
def valid_attribute?(attribute_name)
  self.valid?
  self.errors[attribute_name].blank?
end
```

Or add it to `ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: In fact, this approach might be problematic if you are using some form builders. For example, you may start showing errors on fields which have not been input at all.

Comment: One could run valid? and clear out all errors that are not in the attribute in question instead. That *might* work in some cases.

Comment: This does right the opposite: it validates everything in the background. It is a rather bad practice for the given use case as it will validate the whole object for each attribute.

Comment: can i use this method in controller?

Answer (score 47):

Sometimes there are validations that are quite expensive (e.g. validations that need to perform database queries). In that case you need to avoid using `valid?` because it simply does a lot more than you need.

There is an alternative solution. You can use the [`validators_on`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validators_on) method of `ActiveModel::Validations`.

> validators_on(*attributes) public
>
> List all validators that are being used to validate a specific
>   attribute.

according to which you can manually validate for the attributes you want

e.g. we only want to validate the `title` of `Post`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :body, caps_off: true 
  validates :body, no_swearing: true
  validates :body, spell_check_ok: true

  validates presence_of: :title
  validates length_of: :title, minimum: 30
end
```

Where `no_swearing` and `spell_check_ok` are complex methods that are extremely expensive.

We can do the following:

```
def validate_title(a_title)
  Post.validators_on(:title).each do |validator|
    validator.validate_each(self, :title, a_title)
  end
end
```

which will validate only the title attribute without invoking any other validations.

```
p = Post.new
p.validate_title("")
p.errors.messages
#=> {:title => ["title can not be empty"]
```

#### note

I am not completely confident that we are supposed to use `validators_on` safely so I would consider handling an exception in a sane way in `validates_title`.

Comment: Using `self.class.validators_on` and taking the attribute name as parameter makes it more reusable.

Answer (score 12):

I wound up building on @xlembouras's answer and added this method to my `ApplicationRecord`:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def valid_attributes?(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      self.class.validators_on(attribute).each do |validator|
        validator.validate_each(self, attribute, send(attribute))
      end
    end
    errors.none?
  end
end
```

Then I can do stuff like this in a controller:

```
if @post.valid_attributes?(:title, :date)
  render :post_preview
else
  render :new
end
```

Comment: **There's a bug**: `errors.none?` may refer to other errors (e.g. if this function ran for different attributes previously).

Possible improvements: if you only care about a boolean flag and not the actual errors you may consider returning in the the loop as: `return false unless self.errors[attribute].blank?`. I think `self[attribute]` is nicer than `send(attribute)` but that's only personal preference. Also you may extract it to a concern rather than having it in a parent class (again, preferences).

Comment: @thisismydesign If you want it to return the status just of the specified columns (having run the validations on only the specified columns), I would recommend slicing `errors` before calling `none?`: `errors.slice(*attributes).none?`. This isn't how ActiveModel::Validations tends to handle things though. // 

For what it's worth, accessing attributes with `[]` is not the same as using `send`. The latter will call the accessor method, which is what you want 99/100. 

Also, short-circuiting means not all errors are available for the view to render. That's probably not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @coreyward's answer, I also added a `validate_attributes!` method:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def valid_attributes?(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      self.class.validators_on(attribute).each do |validator|
        validator.validate_each(self, attribute, send(attribute))
      end
    end
    errors.none?
  end

  def validate_attributes!(*attributes)
    valid_attributes?(*attributes) || raise(ActiveModel::ValidationError.new(self))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with other solutions due to `validator.validate_each` being a private method.

Here's a snippet that's working under Rails 6:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def valid_attributes?(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      self.class.validators_on(attribute).each do |validator|
        validator.validate(self)
      end
    end
    errors.none?
  end
end
```

Comment: A nice aspect of using `validator.validate(self)` over `...validate_each` is that it will take `allow_nil` and `allow_blank` options into account. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ae02cd6539d4768718ca7c05201f4514b9f068e9/activemodel/lib/active_model/validator.rb#L150

Comment: A side-effect of using `validate` is that it may validate fields outside or your scope. Example: `validates :email, :first_name, presence: true` and call `valid_attributes?(:email)`, this will then also validate `first_name`.