# Rails 6 - Get error message for single attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to easily get the error message that would be returned for a model validation without all the hassle of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804591/rails-activerecord-validate-single-attribute). Something like:

```
Person.errors(name: "")
-> "Name can't be blank"

Person.errors(name: "___")
-> "Name cannot contain underscores"
```

Why? I want to check error messages in my tests and it would be nice if I could easily get the error message for a single attribute (or multiple) based on the supplied value and not have to build an object with unnecessary parameters and then run valid? or using a string literal that might change later.

**CLARIFICATION:**

There seems to be some questions regarding the question. Suppose a model has 3 different messages (or even just 1) that could be returned based on a particular attribute `username`, called A, B and C. I want to know the exact message that will be returned based on a sample test input I give it. So if I called `User.errors(username: "123")` it would return "Username cannot contain numbers". And if I put in `User.errors(username: "z")` it would return "Username must be 5 or more letters", etc.

The main reason I want this is for a clean in tests to make sure the correct error messages are returned without typing in the literal, so `assert_equal User.errors(username: "z"), flash[:danger]` instead of `"Username must be 5 or more letters", flash[:danger]`

Comment: I would probably settle for send function that generalizes the model and attribute that can be placed in an application helper or something.

Comment: What if there are multiple errors in the record trying to be created?

Comment: Then it would return an array of those messages. But that would be in the case where multiple parameters were provided. A single attribute should have a single error in my case, but I suppose it could have multiple such as 'too long' and 'invalid characters'.

Comment: `@person.errors[:name]`?

Comment: @JoshBrody Thanks, but I need to supply a test string. See clarification above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a custom finder in `app/models/application_record`

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base 
  self.abstract_class = true
  def errors_for(attr)
    errors&.messages&.try(:'[]', attr)                
  end
end
```

And then you could write

```
u = User.new
u.valid?
u.errors_for(:email).include?('is invalid')
```